# Android RecyclerView Endless Scroll adding item throwing Exception For Android Support Library 24.2.1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, endlessscroll

I have implemented the Endless scroll with `RecyclerView`. When user hit the bottom I'm adding `null` object to display progress in `AsyncTask onPreExecute` and notify adapter item Inserted. This code I have been using for quiet some time already. Recently I have updated android Support Library From `23.0.3 to 24.2.1`. Since then I am getting exception when hit bottom of the list.

```
Cannot call this method in a scroll callback. Scroll callbacks might be run during a measure & layout pass where you cannot change the RecyclerView data. Any method call that might change the structure of the RecyclerView or the adapter contents should be postponed to the next frame.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2403)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:4634)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeInserted(RecyclerView.java:10472)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemInserted(RecyclerView.java:6214)
at com.test.film.buzz.BuzzFeedsFragment$5.onPreExecute(BuzzFeedsFragment.java:229)
at com.test.utils.ParallelAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(ParallelAsyncTask.java:595)
at com.test.utils.ParallelAsyncTask.execute(ParallelAsyncTask.java:543)
at com.test.film.buzz.BuzzFeedsFragment.onLoadMore(BuzzFeedsFragment.java:258)
at com.test.film.buzz.BuzzFeedsFragment$3.onScrolled(BuzzFeedsFragment.java:177)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnScrolled(RecyclerView.java:4305)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4463)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445330/cannot-call-notifyiteminserted-method-in-a-scroll-callback-recyclerview-v724-2

Comment: I have added the Handler to postponed to the next frame. Still I am not sure is the right way to do.